# How to copy image to clipboard in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

On my page I want the user to have an option where he clicks the button and the image is saved in the clipboard. I am using this code for this:

```
navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
            'image/png': blob
    })
]);
```

According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write This doesn't work with firefox. But there is no good alternative.

I found this but it's not for webpage only for addons https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/clipboard/setImageData

Also I know that this used to be done with `execComend()` but according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand it's deprecated.

So how can I achieve such a basic task of copying images to clipboard on firefox?

Comment: Sadly, you can't. Firefox has not yet implemented the spec, yet. But could you solve the issue in any other way? What is the use case?

Comment: It is now available on the Nightly